# can someone help me out , why am i getting this error while creating a new compose project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Error:

```
Process: com.example.mydummycomposeapp, PID: 11481
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copy-H99Ercs$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle;JJLandroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontWeight;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontSynthesis;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/BaselineShift;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextGeometricTransform;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/intl/LocaleList;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDecoration;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/Shadow;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDirection;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextIndent;ILjava/lang/Object;)Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle; in class Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle' appears in /data/app/com.example.mydummycomposeapp-3F3AgMqSxVPh6Zp6WnFhcQ==/base.apk)
        at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:284)
        at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.access$withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:188)
        at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:118)
        at com.example.mydummycomposeapp.ui.theme.TypeKt.<clinit>(Type.kt:23)
        at com.example.mydummycomposeapp.ui.theme.TypeKt.getTypography(Type.kt:23)
        at com.example.mydummycomposeapp.ui.theme.ThemeKt.MyDummyComposeAppTheme(Theme.kt:43)
        at com.example.mydummycomposeapp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at com.example.mydummycomposeapp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check with compose version 1.0.0-beta09 , updated on June 16, 2021

```
ext {
    compose_version =  '1.0.0-beta09'
}
```

Comment: thanks brother, it is working with compose version 1.0.0-beta09 & gradle version 1.5